# updating local vector entries in c

Tags: c, pointers, mpi

`int *my_vector` has three values received from master process through MPI_Rec..now i want to subtract the first value from all values and store.e.g

```
my_vector = { 4,8,12}
```

After subtracting first element i.e.4 from all, i need to have these vales{0 4 8} and update/store them in my_vector.

Using following code

```
for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
    my_vector[i]=my_vector[i]-my_vector[0];
}
```

the above code subtract the first element but not others and gives {0 8 12} and not {0,4,8}.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Also tell (or better yet show) us how you know the results. And if you haven't done it yet, then please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I also recommend you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Well you update my_vector[0] first and changed its value to 0, therefore you are now subtracting 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `my_vector[0]` gets the value `0` after first iteration.

Take a copy of my_vector[0] before the loop:

```
tmp = my_vector[0];
for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
    my_vector[i]=my_vector[i]-tmp;
}
```

Another solution is to start the loop from index 1 and change index 0 **after** the loop:

```
for (i=1;i<=2;i++)
{
    my_vector[i]=my_vector[i]-my_vector[0];
}
my_vector[0] = 0;
```

Comment: Or do a reverse loop.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - True, a reverse loop is for sure also a solution. In general I prefer using normal forward loops as I find them more readable. Maybe you should post an answer with a reverse loop. It could be that OP prefers that solution.

Comment: Thanks It worked now..and thanks for the quick response...really appreciate that.....

Answer (score 2):

While a "normal" forward loop using temporary variables might be preferred there is also the alternative of looping backwards:

```
for (i = 2; i >= 0; --i)
{
    my_vector[i] -= my_vector[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

of course, since this code

```
for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
    my_vector[i]=my_vector[i]-my_vector[0];
}
```

sets `my_vector[0]` to zero at first iteration.

you have to store `my_vector[0]` in a local variable to be able to perform the offsetting.

```
int offset=my_vector[0];
for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
    my_vector[i] -= offset;
}
```

Comment: Or do a reverse loop.

Comment: yes, I thought of that, but my experience of reverse loops are not very happy (mistakes with start/end end conditions, incrementations ... :))

Comment: not to mention: the code is clearer (and maybe faster) when copying offset and performing a forward loop (cache/prefetch). Memory/performance tradeoff as always :)